# Log warnings "..before Craft is fully initialized"

Tags: updates, craft4

After updating a site from 3.7 to 4.2.8, in Dev mode and showing the debug toolbar and loading a really simple page (or the control panel) I'm seeing warnings in the log.
I repeated the update process again and get the same result.

I've then tried uninstalling some plugins to trace the cause.

After installing User Manual plugin.

`warning  craft\web\View::createTwig  Twig instantiated before Craft is fully initialized.`

After installing Craft Contact Form plugin

`warning  craft\elements\db\ElementQuery::prepare Element query executed before Craft is fully initialized.`

The site appears to be working fine though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is usually caused by a plugin performing an element query in its `init` method (see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/11033) for more detail). I experienced the same error filling up my log files after upgrading to Craft 4, making debugging any other issues via the logfiles a total pain. I was able to track down the culprit by adding the following code to my `config/app.php` file for my local environment:

```
'local' => [
    'components' => [
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => 20,
        ],
    ],
],
```

(shamelessly cribbed from mmikkel's [post](https://discord.com/channels/456442477667418113/456442867163070466/1006203464570908812) on the Craft Discord)

That gave more detail in the logs that revealed the plugin that was causing the issue, which in my case was the Craft Bulk Edit plugin which was checking user permissions in the `init` method which resulted in element queries, hence the warning.

Hopefully the same process will help you track down what's causing the warnings too.

Comment: That code confirmed that the User Manual plugin is one cause and there is a post on their GitHub issues about it. The other cause is my customised contact-form.php file. I've now posted a seperate post to help solve that issue [link](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/40035/element-query-executed-before-craft-is-fully-initialized)

Answer (score 0):

These are warnings, not errors. You can (and probably should) report these as issues to the respective plugin developers, but everything should continue to work as normal.

Comment: The problem with that is that I have another site that I updated and that also has the contact form plugin and I'm not getting any warning in the log on that site. Which implies there is something else going on here.